# File convert, memory usage (brainstorming)

Tags: .net, memory, ram

I am writing a file converter application which takes A file and converts to B.
The converter method was provided which takes byte[] and returns byte[].

My idea now I read the whole file into a byte[] then I split it to byte[] chunks (so I have basically List<byte[]> and I can see the progress also) due to be able to convert parallel. When the conversion is done optionally can be selected if we want to save or not.

Now if I run this with a large file like 1-2Gb, obviously I am holding the content of the file twice (one what I read and second what I converted) which can cause easily high RAM usage.

What do you think, how could I optimize this?

Side notes:

- Conversion and saving is different action by the user
- One file can be parallel under conversion to different file formats
- Multiple files can be loaded into the application, multiple conversion can be started at the same time (which means more files are read into memory and stored the conversion results too)
- Especially, when at the same time I run multiple files converting to multiple extensions that can be cost large amount of RAM.

Comment: The best way to keep memory usage down is probably to open multiple read streams and read in chunks into small buffers to work on. What do you want to do with the result? Some code would be useful

Comment: Basically, now I read the whole file into a variable, and split to 100 pieces then I am passing each piece to the converter and assembly the converted result and save it. The fact I store the read file and the converted file into variable its already a lot, and I can do these with several files at the same time so the memory usage is increasing. (100 pieces to see how many % is converted already)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of duplicating each section of the `byte[]`, I'd use a `List<Span<byte>>` to reference sections in the original `byte[]`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0

Of course depending on what you're trying to do, this assumes you don't need to reference the original in memory later.